# Why does the Object.Keys.().length is showing non-empty value even it has 0 items in mongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

This is the command prompt output error for `Objects key length`.

[image]

Here `Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length = 34`
Addtasks array length is greater than 0. I dont know why this is showing non-zero value even though in database it has 0 objects list.

Below is the MongoDB schema pic:
[image]

And this is my expressjs code:

```
  router.route("/settingsClients").get(function(req, res) {
        User.findOne({_id:req.user.id}, function(err, data) {
          console.log("Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length =" + Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length );
          if (Object.keys(data.Addtasks).length > 0) {
            console.log("Addtasks length is greater than 0");
            let wordsCount = 0;
            data.Addtasks.forEach(element => {
             wordsCount = wordsCount + element.words;
          });
          let subscriptionTCR = req.user.subscriptionTotalCount - wordsCount;
          res.render('settingsClient',{subscriptionTotalCountRemaining: subscriptionTCR});
        }
         else {
           res.render('settingsClient',{subscriptionTotalCountRemaining: req.user.subscriptionTotalCount});
          }
        });
      })
```

Comment: what could be the another way to calculate the array object's length?

Comment: What are the keys?